# how can Highslide work together with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highslide

Here is my js code

```
define (function (require) {
...
   const hs = require('highslide');
...
    app.directive('anaResult',['$document', function($document) {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
          hs.htmlExpand(scope, { contentId: 'highslide-html' });
        }
      }
    }]);
 ...})
```

then the html

```
<a anaResult>result</a>
<div class="highslide-maincontent">
   something must be show
</div>
```

But when I click the href `result`, the high slide div just not shown, is there any demo code about how the high slide can be used with AngularJS?